# DB2 Table as view in oracle shows character field as varchar2(0 Char)

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, db2, long-integer

I have the following problem: We have a DB2 Table with a Character Field of the size 4000.

Somehow this field gets interpreted in oracle as varchar2(0 Char) when i view it via Oracle Gateway.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW DB2SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE
(

   ID,
   TEXT
)
AS
   SELECT TRIM ("ID") AS ID,
          NULL AS "TEXT
   FROM XT.TEST_TABLE@DB2SCHEMA;
```

Has anybody ever expirienced this issue? For some reason Oracle will treat this field as long. I'm using Oracle 11g. What i want is to show it as normal text field (in DB2 it is a fixed length character field)

Thanks for some inputs and maybe somebody knows how to get this as a normal Varchar2(4000 Char).

DESC XT.TEST_TABLE@DB2SCHEMA;

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Oracle][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver][UDB DB2 for OS/390 and z/OS]UNAVAILABLE       RESOURCE CAUSED FAILED EXEC; 00D70024 TYPE 00000220.      XT.DSNDBC.DSNDB06.DSNDLX04.I0001.A001 {HY000,NativeErr = -904}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from QDBC
```

As before the select * from view did provide a 0 character field we have changed an Oracle Parameter

HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE=LOCAL

This provides the correct result with select * from view. My believe is that this is the solution.

Comment: What's the output of `DESC XT.TEST_TABLE@DB2SCHEMA` in SQL*Plus?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli unfortunately this seems not to work :/ do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: In your select you are only selecting the column "ID" from the remote db, the second column is the constant `NULL`. Can you post the structure of the table on the DB2 side? Which column is being incorrectly translated by the gateway?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli thanks for your input , not selecting is as Null helps :-) too! I tested it with the new parameter and Null is making the result unuseable indeed

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Oracle Gateway or DB2, but any view you create by selecting "null as some_col" is going to define that column as varchar2(0).  You're not even referencing the column you're talking about from the DB2SCHEMA (you're selecting NULL, not the `TEXT` column.

You could try replacing this line:

```
NULL AS "TEXT
```

with:

```
TEXT AS TEXT
```

or possibly:

```
SUBSTR(TEXT,1,2000) || SUBSTR(TEXT,2001,4000) AS TEXT
```

Oracle's maximum size for CHAR columns is [2000](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm), so I'm not sure if you can just select the column directly.

---

**Edit:** As per comments, the OP's issue was fixed via changing the Oracle parameter:

***`HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE=LOCAL`***

Comment: Can you put the Parameter into your result too? So that i can accept it as answer. Thanks

Comment: I could, but I'm not really sure how this parameter affects anything.  Is your view still selecting `null as text`?  If so, I have a hard time believing that this parameter fixes this?  ...or are you now selecting the actual remote column you want (maybe TEXT as TEXT)?

Comment: Hi Gerrat, after having the problem i was selecting it with the * and it would deliver the same result "varchar2(0 Char)" after changing the parameter it has no need to be defined anymore, it seems that this problem is related to non UTF character set definition on the DB2 to a UTF-8 Oracle Instance